# subprocess.getstatus() return limited-length string

Tags: python, linux, subprocess

I use subprocess.getstatus() to get output of bash command running inside python script, in my case top linux command:

`output = subprocess.getoutput("top -bc -n 1 | grep some_process_name")`

Unfortunately, output string of the function is limited to 80 chars. If the string is longer, I just get the first 80 chars.

Any other alternate way to get long outputs in shell commands, in full?

Comment: You can always use `subprocess.Popen` directly and read all the ouput ... but are you sure how top behaves when not attached to a terminal? What happens if you run `ps | grep some_process_name` or just `ls` ... do they also have the 80 character limit?

Comment: The commands you mentioned don't have the 80 character limit. The limit exist only through using getoutput function.

Answer (score 1):

You could pipe the output to a text file, and then display the text file.